# sql Connection .mdf Erorr

Tags: sql-server

I'm coding project Using MS Visual Studio 2017 to enter data to sql Database. when i'm publish the project to another pc its can't connection to sql database show error like image below . the connection string =

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Car_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

[image]

Comment: in my pc the connection is work sucsussfuly
but when i publish the project to another pc its show error above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.